# How to solve PHP warning on dynamic libraries?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_wincache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: artisan
```

Would it be advisable to download the .dll files? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: are you in dev environment or production environment? and which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm at a dev environment and I'm using php version 7.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an old versioned php.ini?

[php_mysql was removed in PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php):

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

So you should remove the line loading php_mysql from your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

WinCache extension is not bundled with PHP and you can [install it using PECL](http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php).